# How do I achieve 50Hz using an astable multivibrator?

Tags: capacitance, frequency

Based on the \$f=1/1.38RC\$ equation I came up with the conclusion that \$R\$ must be 69000 ohms and \$C\$ must be 1000uF, is this correct?

I have a side question:

If I am charging a capacitor without a series resistor, is the only resistance I should include in the \$RC\$ calculation the internal resistance of the power source, maybe with the internal resistance of the capacitor?

I need to know if I charge a 1000uF capacitor without a series resistor, would it take 5000uS (because of the the x5 constant, so 1000uF x 5 = 5000uS or 5ms) or would it be less time assuming the internal resistances total to 0.5ohms, would that mean half the time? 2500uS or 2.5ms?

Comment: There is always some \$R\$, whether it's the wires, PCB traces, power supply, etc.  The equation holds true, \$5RC\$ will get you to 99%. But you need to include the correct \$R\$!

Comment: Your first equation \$f=1/1.38RC\$ is circuit dependant. ie. There is more than one way to make an astable multivibrator.  Post a schematic if you want more help on that.

Comment: Circuit please!  Hit the Edit button.  There is a schematic editor built into the editor.